# How to add same text to several similar kind of files

Tags: macos, bash

I have 70 similar files in a folder. All are similar and contain 3 columns. Now I want to add few lines in the end of the file (after the columns) to all of the them. So same text for all 70 files. Is there any way to do it in one command. I am using Mac OSx. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any particular definition of "similar" in mind?

Comment: Similar in the sense they all contain same parameters just different values. I have to add some text information to all of them. Their name is like file01.dat,file02.dat,file03.dat.......file69.dat.

Answer (score 1):

With a `for` loop.

```
for file in *
do
  cat source/file >> "$file"
done
```